# How to Detect Dark Color Scheme on Windows in PyQt 5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, qt5

On Qt 6.5, as stated by (the document)[https://www.qt.io/blog/dark-mode-on-windows-11-with-qt-6.5], we can now detect if the system is using the dark color scheme by using:

```cpp
static bool shouldApplyDarkFrame()
{
    // ...
    QStyleHints *styleHints = qApp->styleHints();
    return (styleHints->colorScheme() == Qt::ColorScheme::Dark);
}
```

However I need something compatible with Qt version 5 which is also compatible with initial-released color scheme on Windows 10.

The original version of the document stated above is in C++ version and I need something in Python version using PyQt, as mentioned in the title of this question. Are there any ways to detect if the system is using dark theme or not, using PyQt?

```py
def should_apply_dark_frame(self) -> bool:
    ...  # ???
```

By the way, I need the detection for Windows systems only. Qt has a great extensive support for macOS dark scheme since Mojave so no worries about it.

Many thanks.

Comment: AFAIK, this isn't possible on pyqt5. However, the default style on windows is 'windowsvista' and it doesn't have a dark mode. So unless you explicitly set the style to 'fusion' or 'windows', the GUI will be in light mode.

Comment: Doesn't that link explain exactly this.. "Since version 5.15, Qt has provided an opt-in way to use the dark system palette, or to respect the dark system theme at least for the window decoration."

Comment: Python is irrelevant here, the point is what Qt supports, and the linked post clearly says that detection is only available since Qt 6.5. You can *try to assume* the current scheme by querying the application palette and get the colors for the `Window` (background) and/or `WindowText` (foreground) roles, which should theoretically return the system palette even if the current style (notably, windowsvista) doesn't use it.

Comment: You can check the Windows registries: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75457687/detect-dark-application-style-theme-of-currently-used-desktop-in-qt or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65294987/detect-os-dark-mode-in-python

Comment: See this package: https://pypi.org/project/darkdetect/